# Replace every occurrence of a Regex match EXCEPT for the first?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2012

I don't have my code with me at home but I realized that I'll need to do a regex replace on a certain expression and I was wondering if there is a best practices for this.

What my code is currently doing is searching for matches in files, taking those matches out of a file(replacing them with `""`), and then once all the files are processed I make a call to the .NET `Process` class to do some command line stuff. Specifically what i'll be doing is taking a group of files and copying them(merging)into one final output file. But there is the instance where every file to be merged has the exact same first line, which let's just say for the example is:

```
FIRST_NAME|MIDDLE_NAME|LAST_NAME|ADDRESS
```

Now, the first file having that is okay. And I figure that I'm going to do this final match and replace once the file is merged. But I only want to replace matches of that specific expression AFTER the first occurrence.

So, I read that C# has superb support for a Regex look behind? Would that be the proper way to implement "replacing matches after the first occurrence of a match" and if so how would you implement it given a sample regular expression?

My own personal solution to this was to return the amount of files in the folder with `Directory.GetFiles` and then in my `foreach (string file in matches)` I would declare a quick condition that says

```
if (count == directoryCount)
 do not match and replace
 count minus 1
elseif (count < directoryCount) 
 strip matching expression
```

and then every iteration through the `foreach` after the first run-through will strip out the matching expression from the file leaving only the first file with the expression I want to keep.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Id have thought writing the merge step to skip the first line of every file bar the first would be more efficient than merging the files, then having to suck the entire merged file into a big `string` in order to be able to run a regex over it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Instead of using the directory count I just set a bool right before and then changed it to false in the first go through so that the next run through the foreach takes out that one line. Then once of all my files are processed I do a regex.Replace with an empty line identifier that strips out blocks of empty lines with the multiLine property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` has a couple of overloads that provide for `MatchEvaluator evaluator` which is delegate on a `Match` returning the replacement `String`.

So you can use something like `re.Replace(input, m => first ? (first=false, m.Value) : "")` (but I've a VB programmer and have put this in without any syntax checking).

Answer (score 1):

how about using `replaceFirst()` to backup the first occurency and mark it with some char. then use `replaceAll()`, and `replaceFirst()` again to roll back the first match.